# Is it possible to send an attachment in Outlook as a URL

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook addin that handles attachments by sending them to our server and then embedding a link into the body of the email containing the URL to the uploaded attachment.

This works but it is not 100% satisfactory because the URLs can get broken depending in the email client and the sender will not see their attachments listed at the top of there email where they are use to seeing them.

Ideally what I would like to do is exactly what is being done for OneDrive.

Currently if I add an attachment and provide a URL as the source it will download the file and send it as a normal attachment which is the exact opposite of what I want. I have noticed that if it fails to download the file it will then just send the URL as an attachment which is what I want. But sending broken URLs is not very useful.

Using 
Outlook.MailItem.Attachments.Add("https://myserver.com/somefile", 7, 1, "MyAttachment")

If I set the attachment type to '7' which is what is used for OneDrive attachments I can get it to send the URL but it will first complain about not being able to set some access rights  and if the sender clicks OK to continue anyway the attachment will appear to the sender and the receiver as residing on OneDrive which it is not, but clicking the URL will download the file from my server as I want.

My question is: Is it possible to send a none OneDrive URL as an attachment?

(I expect the answer is no, but I am hoping some Outlook guru out there may know some trick to do this.)

My other alternative it to wrap my URLs in an small html file that is then sent as a normal attachment and when opened will provide the link to the actual file.

Comment: Have you tried to create an *.URL file and then attach it using `olByValue `?

Comment: If I do that then Outlook will block the attachment because it deems it to be unsafe.

I have settled on sending a wrapper html file containing my URL. That is simple to do and seems to work.

Comment: I assume that Outlook restricts sending URLs as attachments as a security feature but if that is true then the fact that I have demonstrated 2 ways to 'trick' Outlook into sending my URL as an attachment indicates it is not much of a security feature.

Comment: Does an HTML page work correctly ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by HTML page. Adding an html document as an attachment works.